# Error 404 when using $limit_rate in nginx

Tags: nginx, debian

I have this configuration running on nginx

```
root@homer:/home/admin# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com 
server 
{
listen   80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

## Only allow these request methods (do not accept DELETE, SEARCH and others.. ##
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {return 444; }

location / 
{
    root   /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}


location ~ \.php$ 
{
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    if ($uri !~ "^/upload/") {fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; }

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# Prevent (deny) Access to Hidden Files
location ~ /\.
{
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off; 
    deny all; 
}

# Limit bandwidth rate on a specific folder 
location /download/ 
{ 
    set $limit_rate  150k; 
}   
}
```

My goal is limit the bandwith rate when someone request something from "/download/" directory. With this configuration when I open the browser and I digit something like "example.com/download/filename.example" I recieve 404 error. If I remove the "location /download/" block from the config file, all works good.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

I use nginx/0.7.67 with PHP 5.3.18-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `root` directive for the /download/ location-block.

This can be achieved by either explicitly setting a root directive inside the location-block, or put a global root directive outside the location-blocks, but inside the server-block.

#### Alternative 1 - Explicit root directive inside location-block

```
location /download/ {
  root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
  set $limit_rate 150k;
}
```

#### Alternative 2 - Global root directive for the server-block

```
server {
  root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

...

  location /  {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

...

  location /download/ {
    set $limit_rate 150k;
  }
}
```

Comment: In both alternative configurations, I now receive 403 error

Comment: Check file permissions.